# What does it mean for eGFR to be “normalized” to BSA?

Tags: renal, kidney-disease, laboratory

I’ve seen a few calculators of estimated glomerular filtration rate (eGFR) based on the CKD-EPI mention that

> the equation does not require the patient’s weight, because the
> results are reported normalized to 1.73m^2 body surface area (BSA),
> which is an accepted average adult surface area

(see [NIH calculator](https://www.niddk.nih.gov/health-information/professionals/clinical-tools-patient-management/kidney-disease/laboratory-evaluation/glomerular-filtration-rate-calculators/ckd-epi-adults-conventional-units)).

For the sake of argument, say I have two male patients, both age 60 with the same serum creatinine level. In both patients, the CKD-EPI equation should return the exact same value for eGFR in ml/min/1.73m^2, regardless of their respective BSA.

Setting aside the fact that 1.73m^2 is obviously an underestimate of average BSA for many populations of interest (see [this short article](https://www.nps.org.au/assets/p163-Stefani-et-al.pdf)), what does this “normalization” (some references use the term "indexing") by a reference BSA mean? Is there a mathematical transformation that is applied? Or is it simply the addition of a unit to signify that this estimation reflects the renal function of an idealized patient with a BSA of 1.73m^2?

National Kidney Foundation calculator (with optional BSA adjustment): https://www.kidney.org/professionals/kdoqi/gfr_calculator